# Generalization of Chain Rule for n Composite Functions

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Suppose you have a function $f$ such that $$ f(x) = a(b(c(d(x)))) $$

Where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all differentiable functions. You're asked to find $f'(x)$.

My question is this - Can you "chain" the Chain Rule for 4 functions and state that $$ f'(x) = a'(b(c(d(x)))) *b'(c(d(x)))*c'(d(x))*d'(x) $$

And even more generally, can you apply the same pattern for $n$ functions? I searched three books on this and didn't find a general result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f=a \circ b \circ c \circ d$ you have using chain rule:
$$f'(x)=(a\circ (b \circ c \circ d))'(x)=a'((b \circ c \circ d)(x)) \times (b \circ c \circ d)'(x)$$
using once again chain rule:
$$f'(x)=a'(b(c(d(x)))) \times (b \circ (c \circ d))'(x)=a'(b(c(d(x)))) \times \left[b' \left(( c \circ d)(x)\right)  \times( c \circ d)'(x) \right]$$
and using one last time the chain rule on $c \circ d$ you obtain the result.

*Remark: you can show that the same pattern hold for $n$ function by induction over $n$.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can inductively apply the chain rule for 4 or more functions.